# Migrate to winston 3 and Extend winston logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I want to extend the Winston logger to my custom logger.
Where I updated the log method before calling the internal method.

For Winston version 2.4.x
I did this.

```
var winston = require("winston");

var Logger = function(options){
  Logger.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}
util.inherits(Logger, winston.Logger);

Logger.prototype.log = function () {

  //some logic

  Logger.super_.prototype.log.apply(this, args);

};
```

Now, I am migrating to the Winston version 3.x.x

I migrated the above code as

```
class Logger extends winston.createLogger {

  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
  }

  log() {

    //some logic

    super.log(args);
  };
}
```

The above code is able to create an instance of the logger and start logging the logs but it is not calling my log method instead it's only calling the inbuild Winston log method.